# Central Oil Heater only starts when fan is on

Tags: heater

My heater stopped working.  It started after I put the fan on.  Then it was running for days after I stopped the fan but suddenly stopped working.  Once again I had to put on the fan to start the heater.  Anyone know what this could be?

Comment: It's not clear what type of fan or heater you're talking about.  Central heat?  Space heater?  Is the fan a part of the heater?

Comment: Thank you and sorry.  It's an oil heater and yes the fan is part of the unit.

Comment: Central unit for my home.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What make/model unit is this? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.